# Duvida de Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Como faço pra salvar o Trecho do Log.e  no firebase?
ou em vez de log mudar pra uma forma de salvar no firebase?

no caso esse código pega o numero de childs no firebase e mostra no log, já tentei e não consegui pegar esse resultado. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço :)

```
 mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");


                }


                if (mProcessLike) {


                    if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                        mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                        mProcessLike = false;

                    } else {
                        mDatabaseLike.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(mPost_key);
                        mProcessLike = false;


                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então assim esta no log:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual parte do log você quer salvar?

Comment: snap.getChildrenCount() + ""

Comment: Tentou ver na documentação? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data?hl=pt-br

Comment: Sim já tentei..

Comment: o valor chega zero? Dá ponteiro nulo no dataSnapshot? Acontece o que?

Comment: editei a pergunta...

Comment: Eu não prestei muito a atenção...pra mim tinha que salvar o dado no firebase, não prestei a atençao que o dado vem do firebase (burrice) então por vez não preciso salvar nada só chamar na textview direto.. tipo assim, mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");